# How to Pass ID variable to controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a list of messages and when the click on the title it takes them to another view where they can see the expanded message.

This is the view from which I click the link.

Postings View.

```
<a href="<?=base_url();?>index.php?/Message/display<?=$row['id']?>">Link</a>
```

**Message Controller:**

```
class Message extends CI_Controller {

  var $TPL;

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  private function display()
  {

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT FROM messages WHERE id = '$id';");

    $this->TPL['message'] = $query->result_array();

    $this->template->show('Message', $this->TPL);

  }

  public function index()
  {

     $this->display();

  }
}
```

**Message View**

```
    <?$int=0;?>
    <? foreach ($threads as $row) {  ?>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="message">
        <h3><?= $row['title']?></h3>
        <p><?= $row['message']?></p>
        <p><?= $row['member']?></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>   
    <? $int++;?>      
    <? } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy. Change your code as follwoing

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('message/display').'/'.$row['id'];?>">Link</a>
```

Then change you `display` method as public and send ID param there like

```
public function display($id){
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('messages');
    $this->TPL['message'] = $query->result_array();
    $this->template->show('Message', $this->TPL);
  }
```

And finally remove `$int=0` & `$int++;` from view file as you are not using this. Now test

Answer (score 0):

Change the link

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url().'message/display/'.$row['id'];?>">Link</a>
```

And in your controller

```
public function display() {
$id=$this->uri->segment(3);
if($id==null) {
    redirect('Index');
}
else {
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('messages');
    $this->TPL['message'] = $query->result_array();
    $this->template->show('Message', $this->TPL);
  }
}
```